# "Cannot implicitly convert type 'thisMethod<T>' to 'T'"

Tags: c#, .net, generics, compiler-errors

I'm having trouble with the below code and was hoping someone out there could tell me what's wrong with it.

The error I'm given is:

> Cannot implicitly convert type `ThisThing<T>` to `T`

My code:

```
class ThisThing<T>
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
}

class OtherThing
{
    public T DoSomething<T>(string str)
    {
        T foo = DoSomethingElse<T>(str);
        return foo;
    }

    private T DoSomethingElse<T>(string str)
    {
        ThisThing<T> thing = new ThisThing<T>();
        thing.A = "yes";
        thing.B = "no";

        return thing; // This is the line I'm given the error about
    }
}
```

Thoughts? I appreciate your help!

Comment: Please start the type names with a captial, that makes it so much easier to read. And, please, do not start local variables with an underscore. Or, if you do, start all of them with an underscore. This will help us (and more importantly you) to read the code and prevent errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have told the code that the return type for that method is `T` and you are trying to return a `thisThing<T>`. The compiler has no idea how to convert one from the other so it is complaining to you about it.

You need to either change the return type for your method or change what you are returning in the method.

Answer (score 7):

The methods `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse` have a return type of `T`, whereas you're actually returning a `thisThing<T>` in the body of those methods. These are not the same.

For an easy example, this would be equivalent of returning `List<T>` where you expect just `T` - they're completely different classes.

Answer (score 4):

Well, the compiler says it:

```
private T doSomethingElse<T>(string thisString)
```

would need to be:

```
private thisThing<T> doSomethingElse<T>(string thisString)
```

for it to compile.

Now the fix depends on what are you trying to do (a method which doesn't use its parameter is suspect already).

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is convert the type `thisThing` to the type `T`, which is not possible. Instead, you need to change your return type of `doSomethingElse<T>(...)` to:

```
private thisThing<T> doSomethingElse<T>(...) { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

`thisThing<T>` is a generic type with `T` as the type parameter.  It can't be converted to a `T`.

That would be like saying:

```
List<string> stringList = new List<string>();
string someString = stringList;   // Makes no sense.
```

Answer (score 2):

It's clear for me

`_thisThing` is of type `thisThing<T>` but the return type is of type `T`

Answer (score 1):

```
private thisThing<T> doSomethingElse<T>(string thisString) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your `otherThing` class code like the below code and try

```
class otherThing 
    {
        public otherThing() 
        {
        }
        public thisThing<T> doSomething<T>(string thisString)
        {
            thisThing<T> foo = doSomethingElse<T>(thisString); 
            return foo; 
        }
        private thisThing<T> doSomethingElse<T>(string thisString)
        {
            thisThing<T> _thisThing = new thisThing<T>(); 
            _thisThing.A = "yes";
            _thisThing.B = "no"; 
            return _thisThing; //This is the line I'm given the error about 
        }
    }
```